# Move caret to start line in PhpStorm built in terminal

Tags: phpstorm

I would like to know a shortcut to go to start line in PhpStorm built in terminal. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in terminal is just an inline version of your actual system terminal. So it depends on which Operating System you are using, but the defaults should be:

- On Windows and Linux machines, press the "Home" button.
- On OS X, press CTRL+A.